# I want to find Ip address and Domain name of server whichever we connect by using Ruby.?

Tags: ruby

Means I want to create method which will find Ip address and Domain name of server by using Ruby.

Comment: you should Know How to ask a question on stackoverflow

Comment: @illusionist:: Yes, I have tried by using the Resolv library of ruby               :: require 'resolv'

Comment: @N.V.Prasad:::can you please tell me how to ask question on stackoverflow?

Comment: Nishant, please read this, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and welcome to this community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `socket` from Ruby's standard library

```
require 'socket'
Socket.getaddrinfo("www.ruby-lang.org", "http", nil, :STREAM)
# => [["AF_INET", 80, "carbon.ruby-lang.org", "221.186.184.68", 2, 1, 6]] # PF_INET/SOCK_STREAM/IPPROTO_TCP

IPSocket::getaddress('www.google.com') 
# => "74.125.79.147"
```

For more info you can see
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Socket.html
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/index.html